# UITableViewCell were narrowed when first load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8

[image: narrowed cells]

When the cells first appear,they will look like my picture shows.If scroll top then scroll down let them show again,they will be normal.The top three cells is always being normal while the bottom are narrowed.This is my code`

```
import UIKit

class AllCommentsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func unwindToAllComments(sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    if sender.identifier == "unwindToAllComments"{
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    let photo = ZLLPhoto(withoutDataWithObjectId: "55cd717700b0875fb6cc125f")
    photo.fetch()
    self.photo = photo
}

var photo: ZLLPhoto!

var comments = [ZLLComment]()

@IBAction func commentButtonClicked(sender: UIButton){
    performSegueWithIdentifier("comment", sender: nil)
}

private func initialCommentsQuery() -> AVQuery {
    let query = ZLLComment.query()
    query.whereKey("photo", equalTo: photo)
    query.limit = 20
    query.orderByDescending("likeCount")
    query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
    query.includeKey("score")
    query.includeKey("author")
    return query
}

func getFirst(){
    initialCommentsQuery().findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if objects.count != 0 {
                let comments = objects as! [ZLLComment]
                self.comments = comments

                var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()
                for i in 0..<objects.count{
                    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 2)
                    indexPaths.append(indexPath)
                }

                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .None)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
                self.tableView.footer.endRefreshing()
                self.tableView.footer = MJRefreshAutoNormalFooter(refreshingTarget: self, refreshingAction: "loadMore")
                self.tableView.header = MJRefreshNormalHeader(refreshingTarget: self, refreshingAction: "refresh")
            }
        }else{
            print(error)
        }
        self.tableView.footer.endRefreshing()
    }
  }

func loadMore(){
    let last = comments.last!
    let query = initialCommentsQuery()

    query.whereKey("likeCount", lessThanOrEqualTo: last.likeCount)
    query.whereKey("createdAt", lessThan: last.createdAt)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if objects.count != 0{
                var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()
                for i in 0..<objects.count{
                    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.comments.count + i, inSection: 2)
                    indexPaths.append(indexPath)
                }

                let comments = objects as! [ZLLComment]
                self.comments.extend(comments)

                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .None)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }else{
            print(error)
        }
        self.tableView.footer.endRefreshing()
    }
}

func refresh(){
    let first = comments.first!
    let query = initialCommentsQuery()
    query.whereKey("likeCount", greaterThanOrEqualTo: first.likeCount)
    query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThan: first.createdAt)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if objects.count != 0 {
                var comments = objects as! [ZLLComment]
                comments.extend(self.comments)
                self.comments = comments

                var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()
                for i in 0..<objects.count{
                    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 2)
                    indexPaths.append(indexPath)
                }

                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths,
                    withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()

            }
        }else{
            print(error)
        }
        self.tableView.header.endRefreshing()
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var commentButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var photoTitle: UILabel!{
    didSet{
        photoTitle.text = photo.title
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "comment" {
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! CommentPhotoViewController
        VC.photo = photo
    }else if segue.identifier == "showUser"{
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! UserInfoTableViewController
        VC.user = sender as! ZLLUser
    }
}


@IBAction func likeButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCellContainingView(sender)!
    let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
    let I = ZLLUser.currentUser()
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CommentCell

    if !cell.liked{
        I.likeComment(comment, completion: { (error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                comment.incrementKey("likeCount")
                cell.likeCount += 1
                cell.liked = true
            }else{
                print(error)
            }
        })
    }else{
        I.unlikeComment(comment, completion: { (error) -> Void in
            if error == nil{
                comment.incrementKey("likeCount", byAmount: -1)
                cell.likeCount -= 1
                cell.liked = false
            }else{
                print(error)
            }
        })
    }
}
//XIBload
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet var titleScoreLabel: UILabel?

@IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel?

@IBOutlet var photoCell: UITableViewCell!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("PhotoCell", owner: self, options: nil)

    tableView.footer = MJRefreshAutoNormalFooter(refreshingTarget: self, refreshingAction: "getFirst")

    let query = ZLLScore.query()
    query.whereKey("photo", equalTo: photo)
    query.whereKey("scorer", equalTo: ZLLUser.currentUser())
    query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (count, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if count > 0{
                self.commentButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "comments_add_comment")!, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
        }else{
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

}

extension AllCommentsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("photoCell") as! PhotoCell
        cell.loadPhoto2(photo)
        return cell
    case 1:
        tableView
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentCell
        cell.loadPhotoInfo(photo)
        return cell
    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentCell
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            cell.smallTagImage.image = UIImage(named: "jian")
            return cell
        }
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.loadComment(comments[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section{
    case 2:
        return comments.count
    default:
        return 1
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1 
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    switch section{
    case 0:
        return 1
    default:
        return 10
    }
}
}

extension AllCommentsViewController: PhotoCellDelegate{
func photoCellDidTapUserField(photoCell: PhotoCell) {
}

func photoCellDidClickShareButton(photoCell: PhotoCell) {
    //
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(photoCell)!

    let share = UIAlertController(title: "分享图片", message: "\(photo.title)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
    let weibo = UIAlertAction(title: "微博", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in

        if !WeiboSDK.isWeiboAppInstalled(){
            ZLLViewModel.showHintWithTitle("未安装微博应用", on: self.view)
            return
        }

        if !ShareSDK.hasAuthorizedWithType(ShareTypeSinaWeibo){
            let authorize = UIAlertController(title: "未获取授权", message: "是否要获取授权", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let confirm = UIAlertAction(title: "确认", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                ShareSDK.getUserInfoWithType(ShareTypeSinaWeibo, authOptions: nil, result: { (result, userInfo, errorInfo) -> Void in
                    if !result {
                        ZLLViewModel.showHintWithTitle("授权失败!", on: self.view)
                        return
                    }

                    let image = ShareSDK.imageWithData(self.photo.imageFile.getData(), fileName: "test1", mimeType: "")
                    let content = ShareSDK.content("a", defaultContent: "b", image: image, title: "c", url: "", description: "d", mediaType: SSPublishContentMediaTypeImage)
                    ShareSDK.clientShareContent(content, type: ShareTypeSinaWeibo, statusBarTips: true, result: { (type, state, shareInfo, errorInfo, end) -> Void in

                    })
                })
            })
            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "取消", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
            authorize.addAction(confirm)
            authorize.addAction(cancel)

            self.presentViewController(authorize, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        let image = ShareSDK.imageWithData(self.photo.imageFile.getData(), fileName: "test1", mimeType: "")
        let content = ShareSDK.content("a", defaultContent: "b", image: image, title: "c", url: "", description: "d", mediaType: SSPublishContentMediaTypeImage)
        ShareSDK.clientShareContent(content, type: ShareTypeSinaWeibo, statusBarTips: true, result: { (type, state, shareInfo, errorInfo, end) -> Void in

        })
    }

    let qZone = UIAlertAction(title: "qq空间", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in
        //

        if !QQApiInterface.isQQInstalled(){
            ZLLViewModel.showHintWithTitle("未安装腾讯QQ", on: self.view)
            return
        }

        if !ShareSDK.hasAuthorizedWithType(ShareTypeQQSpace){
            let authorize = UIAlertController(title: "未获取授权", message: "是否要获取授权", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let confirm = UIAlertAction(title: "确认", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                ShareSDK.getUserInfoWithType(ShareTypeQQSpace, authOptions: nil, result: { (result, userInfo, errorInfo) -> Void in
                    if !result {
                        ZLLViewModel.showHintWithTitle("授权失败!", on: self.view)
                        return
                    }

                    let image = ShareSDK.imageWithData(self.photo.imageFile.getData(), fileName: "test1", mimeType: "")
                    let content = ShareSDK.content("a", defaultContent: "b", image: image, title: "c", url: "", description: "d", mediaType: SSPublishContentMediaTypeImage)
                    ShareSDK.clientShareContent(content, type: ShareTypeQQSpace, statusBarTips: true, result: { (type, state, shareInfo, errorInfo, end) -> Void in

                    })
                })
            })
            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "取消", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
            authorize.addAction(confirm)
            authorize.addAction(cancel)

            self.presentViewController(authorize, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        let image = UIImage(data: self.photo.imageFile.getData())
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)

        let attachment = ShareSDK.imageWithData(data, fileName: "test1", mimeType: "")
        let content = ShareSDK.content("a", defaultContent: "b", image: attachment, title: "c", url: "www.baidu.com", description: "d", mediaType: SSPublishContentMediaTypeImage)
        ShareSDK.clientShareContent(content, type: ShareTypeQQSpace, statusBarTips: true, result: { (type, state, shareInfo, errorInfo, end) -> Void in

        })
    }

    let weixin = UIAlertAction(title: "微信好友", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in
        if !QQApiInterface.isQQInstalled(){
            ZLLViewModel.showHintWithTitle("未安装腾讯QQ", on: self.view)
            return
        }

        if !ShareSDK.hasAuthorizedWithType(ShareTypeQQSpace){
            let authorize = UIAlertController(title: "未获取授权", message: "是否要获取授权", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let confirm = UIAlertAction(title: "确认", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                ShareSDK.getUserInfoWithType(ShareTypeQQ, authOptions: nil, result: { (result, userInfo, errorInfo) -> Void in
                    if !result {
                        ZLLViewModel.showHintWithTitle("授权失败!", on: self.view)
                        return
                    }

                    let image = ShareSDK.imageWithData(self.photo.imageFile.getData(), fileName: "test1", mimeType: "")
                    let content = ShareSDK.content("a", defaultContent: "b", image: image, title: "c", url: "", description: "d", mediaType: SSPublishContentMediaTypeImage)
                    ShareSDK.clientShareContent(content, type: ShareTypeQQ, statusBarTips: true, result: { (type, state, shareInfo, errorInfo, end) -> Void in

                    })
                })
            })
            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "取消", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
            authorize.addAction(confirm)
            authorize.addAction(cancel)

            self.presentViewController(authorize, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        let image = ShareSDK.imageWithData(self.photo.imageFile.getData(), fileName: "test1", mimeType: "")
        let content = ShareSDK.content("a", defaultContent: "b", image: image, title: "c", url: "", description: "d", mediaType: SSPublishContentMediaTypeImage)

        ShareSDK.clientShareContent(content, type: ShareTypeQQ, statusBarTips: true, result: { (type, state, shareInfo, errorInfo, end) -> Void in

        })
    }


    let pengyouquan = UIAlertAction(title: "朋友圈", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in

    }

    let cancl = UIAlertAction(title: "取消", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    share.addAction(weibo)
    share.addAction(qZone)
    share.addAction(weixin)
    share.addAction(pengyouquan)
    share.addAction(cancl)
    self.presentViewController(share, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func photoCellDidClickMoreButton(photoCell: PhotoCell) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(photoCell)!

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "更多", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    let report = UIAlertAction(title: "举报", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alertAction) -> Void in
        let confirmReport = UIAlertController(title: "确认举报?", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let delete = UIAlertAction(title: "确认", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive) { (alertAction) -> Void in
            let report = ZLLReport.new()
            report.reportedPhoto = self.photo
            report.reporter = ZLLUser.currentUser()
            let success = report.save()
            if success{
                ZLLViewModel.showHintWithTitle("举报成功", on: self.view)
            }else{
                ZLLViewModel.showHintWithTitle("举报失败", on: self.view)
            }
        }
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "取消", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
        confirmReport.addAction(delete)
        confirmReport.addAction(cancel)
        self.presentViewController(confirmReport, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    alertController.addAction(report)

    if photo.owner.objectId == ZLLUser.currentUser().objectId{
        let delete = UIAlertAction(title: "删除图片", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive) { (alertAction) -> Void in
            let confirmDelete = UIAlertController(title: "确认删除?", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let delete = UIAlertAction(title: "确认", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive) { (alertAction) -> Void in
                let success = self.photo.delete()
                self.photo.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                    if success{
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("deleteComplete", sender: nil)
                        ZLLViewModel.showHintWithTitle("删除成功", on: self.view)
                        self.myPopBackButtonClicked(nil)
                    }else{
                        print(error)
                    }
                })
            }
            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "取消", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
            confirmDelete.addAction(delete)
            confirmDelete.addAction(cancel)
            self.presentViewController(confirmDelete, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alertController.addAction(delete)
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "取消", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}

extension AllCommentsViewController: CommentCellProtocol{
func commentCellDidTapAuthorLabel(cell: CommentCell) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
    let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
    let user = comment.author
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showUser", sender: user)
}
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your `PhotoCell` class, add this snippet code.

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works,thanks.but why I should add this code.My other tableviews will sometimes run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the section where you define your tableView.

In your tableView extension, you set the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method to return 3 rows, so your code defining the cell dimensions only runs on the first 3 rows.

Try setting your `numberOfSections` method to the number of rows you want based on the dimensions of your view, it looks to be about 5.